# How do I get the specific link under h3 tag?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
</div><section class="">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="l-12">
    <div class="l-gi">
                <div class="cards-heading">
    <a href="/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes"><h3>male.celebs</h3></a>
  </div>

  <div class="search-loading-inner hidden"></div>

  <div class="cards-wrap" id="cards-11831178"><div class="group-wrap wrap-3">
      <div class="cards-group collective-group">
        <div class="card-item person" id="content-12357686" data-item-index="0">
  <div class="card-media">
    <div class="card-image">
    <a href="/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/ayden-sng-12357686">
      <img data-sizes="auto" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" data-srcset="/image/13663916/1x1/480/480/f957f70cc7d1c19a3b1d6ccef61118c4/Cp/ayden-sng-2020--tight-shot-.jpg 320w, /image/13663916/1x1/640/640/f957f70cc7d1c19a3b1d6ccef61118c4/Rb/ayden-sng-2020--tight-shot-.jpg 480w" class="lazyautosizes lazyloaded" alt="Ayden Sng 2020 (Tight Shot)" sizes="339px" srcset="/image/13663916/1x1/480/480/f957f70cc7d1c19a3b1d6ccef61118c4/Cp/ayden-sng-2020--tight-shot-.jpg 320w, /image/13663916/1x1/640/640/f957f70cc7d1c19a3b1d6ccef61118c4/Rb/ayden-sng-2020--tight-shot-.jpg 480w">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is the information I get from the website and I'm trying to get the link from

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

import re

def getHTMLdocument(url):

    response = requests.get(url)

    return response.text

url_to_scrape = "https://www.mediacorp.sg/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes"

html_document = getHTMLdocument(url_to_scrape)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_document, 'lxml')

for link in soup.find_all('a',attrs={'href': re.compile("/en/")}):

    print(link.get('href'))
```

however the output from the code only gives me all the links on the page except for the ones under the h3 tag. is there anyway for me to access the codes under the h3 tag?

Comment: Looking at your sample html above, there are no links under an `<h3>` tag. What exactly are you wanting but not getting?

Comment: Yes, there's a `<h3>` tag under a link, but not the opposite; the code seems okay under visual inspection, and should, in theory, work; is the example correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are trying to get the `"/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/ayden-sng-12357686"` links under the `"card-media"` attributes. That data is dynamic and what you are getting in the requests is the static html. You need to use the url that gets back that data.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

def getHTMLdocument(url, payload):

    response = requests.get(url, params=payload)
    return response.text

url_to_scrape = 'https://www.mediacorp.sg/en/toggle/paginateLocalItems'
payload = {
'pageSize': '12',
'pageIndex': '0',
'contentId': '11831178',
'navigationId': '12302270',
'viewType': 'ajaxContentCardListing'}

html_document = getHTMLdocument(url_to_scrape, payload)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_document, 'lxml')

links = []
for link in soup.find_all('a',attrs={'href': re.compile("/en/")}):
    if link.get('href') not in links:
        links.append(link.get('href'))
        print(link.get('href'))
```

You use those parameters in the payload to go get the other pages as well:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

def getHTMLdocument(url, payload):

    response = requests.get(url, params=payload)
    return response.text

url_to_scrape = 'https://www.mediacorp.sg/en/toggle/paginateLocalItems'
links = []

page = 0
while True:
    #print('Page: %s' %(page+1))
    payload = {
    'pageSize': '12',
    'pageIndex': '%s' %page,
    'contentId': '11831178',
    'navigationId': '12302270',
    'viewType': 'ajaxContentCardListing'}
    
    html_document = getHTMLdocument(url_to_scrape, payload)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_document, 'lxml')
    
    if soup.find_all('a',attrs={'href': re.compile("/en/")}) == []:
        break
    
    for link in soup.find_all('a',attrs={'href': re.compile("/en/")}):
        if link.get('href') not in links:
            links.append(link.get('href'))
            print(link.get('href'))
           
    page+=1
```

**Output:**

```
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/ayden-sng-12357686
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/ben-yeo-12357544
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/benjamin-tan-12357684
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/brandon-wong-12357582
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/bryan-wong-12357546
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/cavin-soh-12357626
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/chen-han-wei-12357548
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/chen-shu-cheng-12357584
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/chen-tian-wen-12357586
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/chen-yi-xi-12357646
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/chew-chor-meng-12357588
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/desmond-ng-12357570
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/desmond-tan-12357590
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/edwin-goh-12357550
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/elvin-ng-12357552
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/glenn-yong-14218688
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/guo-liang-12357592
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/herman-keh-12357682
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/ian-fang-12357594
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/james-seah-12357596
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/jarrell-huang-12357654
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/jeffrey-xu-12357554
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/jeremy-chan-15172284
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/lee-teng--12357630
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/mark-lee-12357632
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/nick-teo-12357598
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/pierre-png--12357556
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/qi-yuwu-12357600
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/rayson-tan-12357562
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/richard-low-12357602
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/richie-koh-12357642
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/romeo-tan-12357558
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/shaun-chen-12357560
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/terence-cao-12357604
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/tyler-ten--12357694
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/yao-wen-long-12357564
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/zane-lim-12357692
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/zhai-siming--12357690
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/zhang-yao-dong-12357568
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/zhang-ze-tong--12357688
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/zheng-ge-ping-12357622
/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/zhu-hou-ren-12358080
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much, this is something that i was eventually trying to work towards! if i may ask, how did you obtain the url 'https://www.mediacorp.sg/en/toggle/paginateLocalItems'? I'm trying to make it such that I can have the scraper obtain links from the dropdown menu(all four options, male artistes, female artistes, male djs and female djs. 

I've tried looking through the elements of the page to look for the link but could not find it

Comment: Look at the dev tools -> Network-> XHR. I’ll look tomorrow to see if I can find those parameters to get those others. Meanwhile make sure to accept the solution.

Answer (score 1):

As alternativ approach to `requests` you can also go with [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html) to get the urls.

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('YOUR PATH TO DRIVER')
driver.get('https://www.mediacorp.sg/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes')

soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

[x['href'] for x in soup.select('div.card-item h3 > a')]
```

#### Output - List with urls

```
['/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/ayden-sng-12357686',
 '/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/ben-yeo-12357544',
 '/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/benjamin-tan-12357684',
 '/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/brandon-wong-12357582',
 '/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/bryan-wong-12357546',
 '/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/cavin-soh-12357626',
 '/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/chen-han-wei-12357548',
 '/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/chen-shu-cheng-12357584',
 '/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/chen-tian-wen-12357586',
 '/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/chen-yi-xi-12357646',
 '/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/chew-chor-meng-12357588',
 '/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/desmond-ng-12357570']
```